# No puedo lograr que se dibuje el personaje en la pantalla

Tags: python, pygame

Estoy intentando hacer que mi personaje (`imag_1`) se dibuje en la pantalla pero no lo consigo. Este es mi código:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import K_LEFT, K_UP, K_RIGHT, K_DOWN
import os
import sys
# Variables

imag_1 = pygame.image.load('prueba_Pers.png')

Verde = (90, 133, 52)
Negro = (0, 0, 0)

Ancho = 700
Altura = 500
An_Lag = (Ancho, Altura)
height = 20

x = 0
y = 0
# Inicia pygame

pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(An_Lag)  
screen.fill(Verde)
pygame.display.set_caption("Prueba")
pygame.display.flip()


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x -= 10
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x += 10
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y += 10
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y -= 10

clock.tick(60)
pygame.blit(imag_1, (50, 50))
screen.display.flip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a [es.so].  Te recomiendo que realices el [tour] y leer [ask]. A tu pregunta le falta mas información, como que es lo que te falla exactamente y alguna descripción para poder entender el contexto de lo que planteas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes varios problemas en tu código:

- Las tres últimas líneas están mal identadas, deben estar dentro del mainloop. Esto posiblemente sea un error al copiar el código, si no lo es debes corregirlo.
- `blit` es un método de `pygame.Surface`, por lo tanto no es `pygame.blit` es `screen.blit`. Además, si quieres que tu personaje se mueva debes usar las variables `x` e `y`, es decir   `screen.blit(imag_1, (x, y))`.
- Por contra `screen.display.flip()` debe ser `pygame.display.flip()`.
- Esto no es un error en sí, pero no debes encadenar varios `if` en la comprobación del evento. Si una condición se cumple no tiene sentido comprobar si el evento es de otro tipo, esto es ineficiente. En su lugar usa `if - elif`.
- Para que cuando tu personaje cambie de posición no se dibujen también las posiciones anteriores (traza) debes rellenar la pantalla con el fondo de nuevo cada vez que esto ocurra. Es decir, debes hacer un `screen.fill` dentro del mainloop. En determinados casos por eficiencia es recomendable actualizar solo la parte de la ventana dónde el sprite estaba antes.
- En PyGame el origen de las coordenadas de la pantalla está situado en el vértice superior izquierdo de la misma. Por lo tanto debes aumentar `y` cuando se pulsa `K_DOWN` y reducirla cuando se pulsa `K_UP`, a no ser que quieras invertir el desplazamiento.

Con esto ya se muestra tu personaje y puedes moverlo:

```
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import K_LEFT, K_UP, K_RIGHT, K_DOWN



VERDE = (90, 133, 52)
ANCHO = 700
ALTO = 500

imag_1 = pygame.image.load('prueba_Pers.png')
x = 0
y = 0

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ANCHO, ALTO))  
pygame.display.set_caption("Prueba")


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x -= 10
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x += 10
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y -= 10
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y += 10

    screen.fill(VERDE)
    screen.blit(imag_1, (x, y))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

> **Nota:** La imagen se desplaza 10 pixeles cada vez que se pulsa una de las teclas. Para permitir que la imagen se desplace de forma continuada mientras la tecla esté pulsada se debe habilitar mediante [`pygame.key.set_repeat`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.set_repeat), lo que permite que mientras una tecla esté pulsada se generen eventos `KEYDOWN` de forma continuada.

A pesar de que lo anterior funcione en principio, lo normal es usar un [sprite](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) para esto:

```
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import K_LEFT, K_UP, K_RIGHT, K_DOWN



# Constantes
VERDE = (90, 133, 52)
ANCHO = 700
ALTO = 500


# Clase que representa nuestro Sprite
class Personaje(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('prueba_Pers.png') 
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.vel = 10


    def update(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[K_DOWN]: 
           self.rect.y += self.vel 
           if self.rect.bottom > ALTO:
              self.rect.bottom = ALTO 

        if keys[K_UP]: 
           self.rect.y -= self.vel 
           if self.rect.top < 0:
              self.rect.top = 0  

        if keys[K_RIGHT]: 
           self.rect.x += self.vel
           if self.rect.right > ANCHO:
              self.rect.right = ANCHO    

        if keys[K_LEFT]: 
           self.rect.x -= self.vel 
           if self.rect.left < 0:
              self.rect.left = 0     


# Inicia pygame
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ANCHO, ALTO))
pygame.display.set_caption("Prueba")
pygame.key.set_repeat(1, 25) 

# Sprite
personaje_sprite = Personaje()
# Grupo para el sprite
personaje = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle()
personaje.add(personaje_sprite)


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    screen.fill(VERDE)
    personaje.update()
    personaje.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Como se puede ver en el método `update` del sprite se comprueba cada vez que se mueve si su posición excede los límites de la pantalla, en caso de no hacerlo el sprite puede salir de ella dejado de estar visible.